# Cordova количество запусков?

Tags: mysql, ios, phonegap, cordova

Добрый день, кто-нибудь знает решение. Почти доделал свое приложение, скоро выложу его в app store, но вот задумался, а как узнавать какое количество людей ежедневно открывают мое приложение? Приложение работает с бд и можно туда писать, обновлять счетчик, но пока не нашел параметр, который с этим работает. Кто-то знает как это отслеживать?

Answer (score 1):

Как и в плей маркете есть статистика по установками и активным приложениям, на крайний случай есть плагин для аналитикса

Answer (score 0):

Добавь Гугл Аналитику. Потом на сайте сможешь посмотреть количество пользователей в день, количество новых пользователей, количество сессий и тд.